# Assign a Javascript function to AjaxOptions OnSuccess property raise an error - ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax

I'm using the Ajax.ActionLink helper to generate a link to delete a record. This is the code:

```
Ajax.ActionLink("Delete Image", "DeleteImage", new { id = item.Id },
                                               new AjaxOptions { HttpMethod = "Delete", OnSuccess = "Test()" } )
```

I'm assign a Javascript function (Test()) to the OnSucess property because I want to do some JQuery stuff, but when I click the Delete link this error message is raised

> Microsoft JScript runtime error: 'b' is null or not an object

in the MicrosoftAjax.js file (Line 5, Column 62099). If I remove the OnSuccess property, everything works fine (even if the Test() function is empty, the same error is raised). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 20, accepted):

```
OnSuccess = "Test()"
```

you have to write it like this it is a callback...

```
OnSuccess = "Test"
```

Comment: Can I access values returned from that action like Json?

Comment: How do I pass `this` (i.e. the generated anchor) to the js function?

Answer (score 14):

If you have to pass any parameter to the OnSuccess event you may have to write the funcion in this way.

```
OnSuccess = "function(){exampleFunction('" + param1 + "');}"
```

Answer (score 0):

To pass a parameter, an anonymous function won't work, you need to do something like this:

```
OnSuccess = String.Format("Test({0})", param)
```