# How to update a div with Ajax.BeginForm AND execute a javascript function?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-ajax, partial-views

I am updating a div with a partial view by using something like this:

```
<% using (Ajax.BeginForm("Action", "Controller",
               new { id=Model.id },
               new AjaxOptions
               {
                   UpdateTargetId = "divId",
                   InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertAfter,
               }))
   {  %>
```

and its working fine, the returned view gets appened to the div, however I now need to execute a javascript when the post is successful, so I thought: "easy, just add  `OnSuccess = "MyJsFunc()"` "  to the `AjaxOptions`, but after doing this, it stopped working! now the page is refreshed and only the returned partial view is rendered :(, I even tried with a simple `Alert("Hi")` and its nor working.. how can I get this to work?

(by the way I think this can be a dup of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1994754/execute-javascript-after-loading-a-mvc-page-using-ajax-beginrouteform but that question got abandoned with no answer)

Comment: +1 on this question; I believe I have seen the same behavior myself; using ASP.NET 4.0 with MVC2 and C#. Every time I add an OnSuccess member value to the AjaxOptions, the Ajax form seems to turn into a regular form. I've just started using jQuery.form to submit such forms now, but I'd like to figure this out, too!

Comment: Hmm I am also using ASP.NET 4 and MVC2 and C#

Comment: possible duplicate of [Assign a Javascript function to AjaxOptions OnSuccess property raise an error - ASP.NET MVC](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/695729/assign-a-javascript-function-to-ajaxoptions-onsuccess-property-raise-an-error-a)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Any reason for not doing it the right way (after all we are in 2010)? Dump MS AJAX where it belongs along with all the `Ajax.*` helpers which depend on it and write proper code. While using MS AJAX in classic webforms could have been justified because of the UpdatePanels, etc... doing it in a new ASP.NET MVC application today, especially after Microsoft have fully embraced jQuery, seems like a bad idea.

So after the rant here's my recommendation:

```
<% using (Html.BeginForm("Action", "Controller", new { id = Model.id }) { %>
```

and then attach the submit handler unobtrusively using jquery in a separate file:

```
$(function() {
    $('form').submit(function() {
        $.ajax({
            url: this.action,
            type: this.method,
            success: function(result) {
                // feel free to execute any code 
                // in the success callback
                $('#result').html(result);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

or using the excellent [jquery form plugin](http://jquery.malsup.com/form/):

```
$(function() {
    $('form').ajaxForm(function(result) {
        // feel free to execute any code 
        // in the success callback
        $('#result').html(result);
    });
});
```

Benefits of this approach:

- Unobtrusive
- Clear separation between markup and javascript
- Caching javascript files and decreasing bandwidth usage

Bonus benefit: no headaches.

Comment: How can I pass the model id to the .ajax function?

Comment: @Nick Masao, you could include it as hidden field inside the form.

Comment: @Nick Masao, you can also include a 'data' option in the options block being passed to the ajax option.  I.E. $.ajax({..., data:{ id: @Model.id }, ...});

Comment: Somehow or the other my browser still asks me to save the JSON file... Why does it do that?  Maybe if I had some clue, it could help me get over this hump.

Comment: @DmainEvent, which of the 2 approaches are you using? If you are using the jquery.form plugin and your form contains file inputs and you are using IE, make sure you have [read the documentation](http://malsup.com/jquery/form/#file-upload) and wrapped your JSON response in `<textarea>` tags.

Comment: I am not using the jquery.form plugin...  I am using the first technique...  Somehow or the other, my ('form').submit never seem to call... I should check to see if I have the right tags...  I updated a question of mine... if you want to look at it, I would appreciate it http://stackoverflow.com/q/10839908/729820

Comment: @DmainEvent, your question seem to be already answered. There's an accepted answer.

Comment: yes, the initial question was answered, I recently updated it.  I could take away the answer, but I thought the question was similar enough there was no reason to add a whole new question.  Although I did...
http://stackoverflow.com/q/11531143/729820

Answer (score 5):

I kept looking around and found the answer here:

[Assign a Javascript function to AjaxOptions OnSuccess property raise an error - ASP.NET MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/695729/assign-a-javascript-function-to-ajaxoptions-onsuccess-property-raise-an-error-a) (with the answer that was not selected)

Quoting [Atzu](https://stackoverflow.com/users/438110/atzu)

> If you have to pass any parameter to
>   the OnSuccess event you may have to
>   write the funcion in this way.

```
OnSuccess = "function(){exampleFunction('" + param1 + "');}
```

and it worked for me!