# is ajax.beginform obsolete

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc-2, asp.net-ajax

I read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3840967/how-to-update-a-div-with-ajax-beginform-and-execute-a-javascript-function)  and I would like to know if `Ajax.BeginForm` is obsolete

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well, it's not obsolete, but Darin in the question you have linked to feels strongly against using it.

Personally, MVC 2's client side solution in some ways feels like a mixed bag and I can only surmise that this is because Microsoft fully embraced jQuery as the JavaScript library after effort had been put in to writing all the AJAX helpers using the MS AJAX library. I've found that you need to plug in the jQuery stuff that you need to use with MVC 2 as the framework primarily focused on using MS AJAX. A perfect example of this is client side validation; whilst the MVC Futures contained a jQuery validation "glue" script to hook the outputted meta data up to the jQuery validation plugin, in a lot of ways it was rough and unpolished (about 15 functions in global scope for a start!); I guess that's why it was in futures :)

Thankfully that has changed in MVC 3, which puts jQuery at the forefront of the client side solution.

Comment: So does that mean I should or should'nt use it?

Comment: Are you using the MS AJAX library? If you are then the Ajax helpers would save you the time to have to write those things yourself. If you're using another library and don't want to take the dependency on the MS AJAX library then don't use them. If you're comfortable enough in implementing the functionality yourself, then there is no need to use the helpers.

Comment: @user351709, no, you should not use it. Things have changed since I posted this answer. We are now in 2011 which is one more reason to throw away Ms Ajax :-)